# Device not going to Power off

Tags: movesense

I am reusing the following piece of code hr_wakeup app.
counter = counter + LED_BLINKING_PERIOD;

```
if (counter < AVAILABILITY_TIME)
{
    asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::UI_IND_VISUAL(), AsyncRequestOptions::Empty,
             WB_RES::VisualIndTypeValues::SHORT_VISUAL_INDICATION);
    return;
}

if (counter >= AVAILABILITY_TIME)
{
    // Prepare AFE to wake-up mode
    asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::COMPONENT_MAX3000X_WAKEUP(),
             AsyncRequestOptions(NULL, 0, true), (uint8_t)1);

    // Make PUT request to switch LED on
    asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::COMPONENT_LED(), AsyncRequestOptions::Empty, true);

    // Make PUT request to enter power off mode
    asyncPut(WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_MODE(), AsyncRequestOptions(NULL, 0, true), // true = Force async
             WB_RES::SystemModeValues::FULLPOWEROFF);
}
```

I have enabled Level 4 logs and I see the following
2022-01-11 13:59:52.693 14817-14817/D/LocationUpdatesServiceWithSensor: DEBUG LOG {"Body": {"Id": null, "Timestamp": 114284, "Level": 4, "Tag": "", "Message": "LedService::onPutRequest() called."}, "Uri": "184730000180/System/Debug/4", "Method": "PUT"}
2022-01-11 13:59:52.698 14817-14817D/LocationUpdatesServiceWithSensor: DEBUG LOG {"Body": {"Id": null, "Timestamp": 114284, "Level": 4, "Tag": "", "Message": "MAX3000X wake set to: 1"}, "Uri": "184730000180/System/Debug/4", "Method": "PUT"}

However, the device is not getting powered off. I can see the device in the phone.
I am using bootloader 2.0 and hence is there any change the api call I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the lead's detection in the startModule().
you will find the below code in the hrs_wakeup_app's startModule(0. do the same with your code.

```
// Subscribe to leads detection
asyncSubscribe(WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_STATES_STATEID(), AsyncRequestOptions::Empty, WB_RES::StateIdValues::CONNECTOR);
```

I am assuming you have already figured it out, as this was asked a year ago. I have started working with movesense recently and got this problem too. So just posting if anyone needs it.